# how to make twitter bootstrap submenu to open on the left side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to create twitter bootstrap submenu in dropdown menu, but I've got a problem: I have dropdown menu in the top right corner of the page and that menu has one more submenu. However, when submenu opens - it does not fit in the window and goes too much to the right, so that user can see only first letters. How to make that submenu to open not to the right, but to the left?

Comment: Post the snippet code.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, add `.pull-right` on the `.dropdown` container.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add the `pull-left` class to your `dropdown-submenu`

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
```

jsfiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/szx4Y/51/)

Comment: This answer along with the one by Matt for at the UL level are the correct way to implement this when using bootstrap.

Comment: OP's question and my answer are from august 2012. Meanwhile, Bootstrap is changed, so now you have .pull-left class. Back then, my answer was correct. Now you don't have to manually set css, you have that .pull-left class.

Comment: This works nicely for some cases, but breaks if the items in the main menu are too long, as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/446/

Anyone have a quick idea for a fix?

Comment: @AaronLifshin `.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu { width: 100%; }`  Not an elegant solution, but seems to work  http://jsfiddle.net/r1v90tas/

Comment: @Schmalzy looking at it further, width:100% causes a different issue with long items in the submenu http://jsfiddle.net/r1v90tas/1/ and that is fixed by using min-width:100% instead, as per here: http://jsfiddle.net/r1v90tas/2/

Comment: It will not work with long menu name. Try editing jsfiddle and enter "Benchmarking Experience Project Workbook Data Dictionary" in any sub menu.

Answer (score 118):

If I've understood this right, bootstrap provides a CSS class for just this case. Add 'pull-right' to the menu 'ul':

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
```

..and the end result is that the menu options appear right-aligned, in line with the button they drop down from.

Comment: absolutely, i needed the main menu, not the submenu to move over. so i needed to target the <ul> element. it's confusing because you want to move it to the left, however you use `pull-right` class to achieve this.

Comment: This answer is valid for Bootstrap 3.x, so, looks like it is the most correct one at this moment.

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't work for me and Bootstrap 3, but this one does!

Comment: thanks, It's works but it is kind of counter intuitive.. add `pull-right` to make it appear on left?

Comment: This is correct. add .pull-right and your dropdown will not go off the right hand side of the screen!

Comment: use .dropdown-menu-right

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment

Comment: `pull-right` should be applied at the `ul` level, not the `li` level.  This should  be the accepted answer

Answer (score 26):

Curent class `.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu` have `left: 100%;`. So, if you want to open submenu on the left side, override those settings to negative left position. For example `left: -95%;`. Now you will get submenu on the left side, and you can tweak other settings to get perfect preview.

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mQnv2/1/)

EDIT: OP's question and my answer are from august 2012. Meanwhile, Bootstrap changed, so now you have .pull-left class. Back then, my answer was correct. Now you don't have to manually set css, you have that .pull-left class.

EDIT 2: Demos aren't working, because Bootstrap changed their URL's. Just change external resources in jsfiddle and replace them with new ones.

Comment: Thanks. Almost exactly what I need, however, there should be `left: -90%;` (otherwize I can't move my mouse to that submenu, cause it disappears).

Comment: Like i said, that is just idea what you need to do. Glad i'm helped :)

Comment: Your example only works for certain cases. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQnv2/305/

Comment: This is not the correct answer as the bootstrap classes should be used as mentioned in Schmalzy and Matt's posts.

Comment: This post is a whole year older. Meanwhile, bootstrap is changed so Schmalzy's answer is more elegant. Back then, Bootstrap didn't have pull-left class.

Comment: Bootstrap changed again. Should now be `.dropdown-menu-right` instead of `.pull-left` (yes right, see my jsfiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/yqt4hfbj/

Answer (score 22):

If you are using bootstrap v4 there is a new way to do that.

You should use `.dropdown-menu-right` on  the `.dropdown-menu` element.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Right-aligned menu
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to code: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-items

Comment: This also works for boostrap versions >= 3.1... check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19253730/3354228

Comment: definitly easiest answer

Comment: This is somewhat correct for version 4.  The syntax has changed to `dropleft` and `dropright` but the context of the answer is correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to do the task is:

```
/* Submenu placement itself */
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu { left: auto; right: 100%; }
/* Arrow position */
.dropdown-submenu { position: relative; }
.dropdown-submenu > a:after { position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 3px; float: none; border-right-color: #cccccc; border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0; }
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after { border-right-color: #ffffff; }
```

Comment: More of a preference
`.dropdown-submenu { position: relative; text-align:right; }`
To position the text to the right when the arrow is to the left.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a javascript function that looks if he has enough space on the right side.
If it has he will show it on the right side, else he will display it on the left side

Tested in:

- Firefox (mac)
- Chorme (mac)
- Safari (mac)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //little fix for the poisition.
    var newPos     = $(".fixed-menuprofile .dropdown-submenu").offset().left - $(this).width();
    $(".fixed-menuprofile .dropdown-submenu").find('ul').offset({ "left": newPos });

    $(".fixed-menu .dropdown-submenu").mouseover(function() {
        var submenuPos = $(this).offset().left + 325;
        var windowPos  = $(window).width();
        var oldPos     = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
        var newPos     = $(this).offset().left - $(this).width();

        if( submenuPos > windowPos ){
            $(this).find('ul').offset({ "left": newPos });
        } else {
            $(this).find('ul').offset({ "left": oldPos });
        }
    });
});
```

because I don't want to add this fix on every menu items I created a new class on it.
place the fixed-menu on the ul:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu fixed-menu">
```

I hope this works out for you.

ps. little bug in safari and chrome, first hover will place it to mutch to the left will update this post if I fixed it.

Comment: +1:  I made a few changes, but this lead me to a working solution.

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 4):

If you have only one level and you use bootstrap 3 add `pull-right` to the `ul` element

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually - if you are ok with floating the `dropdown` wrapper - I've found it to be as easy as to add `navbar-right` to the `dropdown`.

This seems like cheating, since it's not in a navbar, but it works fine for me.

```
<div class="dropdown navbar-right">
...
</div>
```

You can then further customize the floating with a `pull-left` directly in the `dropdown`...

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left navbar-right">
...
</div>
```

... or as a wrapper around it ...

```
<div class="pull-left">
  <div class="dropdown navbar-right">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LESS CSS, I wrote a little mixin to move the dropdown with the connecting arrow:

```
.dropdown-menu-shift( @num-pixels, @arrow-position: 10px ) {  // mixin to shift the dropdown menu
    left: @num-pixels;
    &:before { left: -@num-pixels + @arrow-position; }        // triangle outline
    &:after  { left: -@num-pixels + @arrow-position + 1px; }  // triangle internal
}
```

Then to move a `.dropdown-menu` with an id of `dropdown-menu-x` for example, you can do:

```
#dropdown-menu-x {
    .dropdown-menu-shift( -100px );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a javascript function that looks if he has enough space on the right side. If it has he will show it on the right side, else he will display it on the left side. Again if it has has enough space on the right side, it will show right side. it is a loop...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'visible');

if (screenWidth > 767) {

    $(".dropdown-submenu").hover(function () {

        var dropdownPosition = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() + $(this).find('ul').width();
        var newPosition = $(this).offset().left - $(this).find('ul').width();
        var windowPosition = $(window).width();

        var oldPosition = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
        //document.title = dropdownPosition;
        if (dropdownPosition > windowPosition) {
            $(this).find('ul').offset({ "left": newPosition });
        } else {
            $(this).find('ul').offset({ "left": oldPosition });
        }
    });

}
```

});

Comment: it works! But lets limit it: var newPosition = Math.max(10,...);

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of bootstrap? I have adapted the html from [the Fluid Layout example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html) as shown below. I added a drop down and placed it furthest to the right hand side by adding the `pull-right` class. When hovering over the drop down menu it is automatically pulled to the left and nothing is hidden - all the menu text is visible. I have not used any custom css.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown open">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
          Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. This is just dropdown (I also use pull-right or pull-left). But I need to open submenu IN SUBMENU and to make it open to the left (in dropdown should be arrow indicating the existence of the submenu which should open to the left, but not right, as the standard one does).

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to do is

```html
 <ul style='left:-100%'>
```

of the menu which you want to display on RIGHT side.