# How to make Primefaces submenu open on the left side?

Tags: css, jsf, menu, primefaces

I have a `p:tieredMenu` under which is a `p:subMenu` which is loaded with a list of `p:menuItem`. I have the tiered menu on the right corner of the page, so when the sub menu opens, it opens on the right side and moves out of the page.

Please let me know if there is any way to make the sub menu appear on the left side.

I had a look at a similar question [How to make twitter bootstrap submenu to open on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187554/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-submenu-to-open-on-the-left-side), but do not know how to implement that with respect to Primefaces/JSF.

Answer (score 0):

This property will get the menu blocks to appear on the left side.But this will cause all the menus to be on the left side.

```
.ui-menu-child {
   left: -200px !important;
}
```

You would need to play around a bit to get exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG 11

```
#yourMenuId .p-submenu-list {
  right: 100%;
  left: unset;
}
```