# change bootstrap drop down to drop horizontal right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that opens a row of icons underneath it (see picture 1, names and pictures were removed to maintain privacy)
[image]

I am trying to make this menu to open to the right of choose child, and not underneath it (see picture 2, of what I am trying to get. the Images will open to the right of the drop down and not under it)
[image]

My current code is:

```
<div class="span4">      
        <div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  <h3>Choose Child</h3>
  <img id="mainIcons" src="boyStudent.png" alt="boyStudent">
  <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="parent_homepage_2.html" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
       <h5>A</h5>
       <img id="mainIcons" src="boyStudent.png" alt="boyStudent"></a>
       <a href="parent_homepage_2.html" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
       <h5>J</h5>
       <img id="mainIcons" src="girlStudent.png" alt="girlStudent"></a>
     </div>
    </li> 
  </ul>
```

I tried to use the following example, that helps push the drop down to the left 
[how to make twitter bootstrap submenu to open on the left side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187554/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-submenu-to-open-on-the-left-side)
but I could not figure out a way to use this to what I am looking to do

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How does this look:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PbajH/)

### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/DL2af/) Submenu dropping down.

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              <h3>Choose Child</h3>
              <img id="mainIcons" src="boyStudent.png" alt="boyStudent">
               <span class="right-caret right"></span>
         </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li>
                <div class="btn-group"> <a href="parent_homepage_2.html" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                   <h5>A</h5>
                   <img id="mainIcons" src="boyStudent.png" alt="boyStudent"></a>
 <a href="parent_homepage_2.html" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-link operationsButtons">
                   <h5>J</h5>
                   <img id="mainIcons" src="girlStudent.png" alt="girlStudent"></a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

### css

```
   .rightMenu {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
.right-caret {
    
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
    
}
.right
{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: No Problem... I am glad that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I just add this class to the `dropdown-menu`:

```
.rightMenu {
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    top: 0;
    left: 160px;
}
```

And it aligns perfectly.

Comment: Also, you can use `left: 100%` if you do not know the width.

Comment: Works superbly!

Answer (score 4):

Just add the class "pull-right" into the `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` this way...

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
     <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This will make the sub menu open underneath still, just right-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

To those who may find this page in the future, the now official way of doing this is with adding the `.dropdown-menu-right` class to your dropdown list.

Comment: That is incorrect. `.dropdown-menu-right` makes the right edge of the dropdown align with the right edge of the button. It does not move the dropdown to the side of the button.