# Bootstrap: Position of dropdown menu relative to navbar item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have the following dropdown

```
<label class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
    Action <b class="caret"></b></label>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="lang-selector" id="lang-selector">
    dropdown content goes here
</ul>
```

The upper-left corner of the dropdown is at the lower-left corner of the text (Action), but I hope that the position of the upper-right corner of the dropdwon is at the lower-right place of the text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

This is the effect that we're trying to achieve:

[image: A right-aligned menu]

The classes that need to be applied changed with the release of Bootstrap 3.1.0 and again with the release of Bootstrap 4. If one of the below solutions doesn't seem to be working **double check the version number of Bootstrap that you're importing** and try a different one.

#### Before v3.1.0

You can use the `pull-right` class to line the right hand side of the menu up with the caret:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
     <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joeczucha/ewzafdju/

#### After v3.1.0

> As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated .pull-right on dropdown menus. To
> right-align a menu, use .dropdown-menu-right. Right-aligned nav
> components in the navbar use a mixin version of this class to
> automatically align the menu. To override it, use .dropdown-menu-left.

You can use the `dropdown-right` class to line the right hand side of the menu up with the caret:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Link</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joeczucha/1nrLafxc/

### Bootstrap 4

The class for Bootstrap 4 are the same as Bootstrap > 3.1.0, just watch out as the rest of the surrounding markup has changed a little:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    Link
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joeczucha/f8h2tLoc/

### Bootstrap 5

Again, very similar for Bootstrap 5 except now it's `dropdown-menu-end`

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    Link
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">...</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joeczucha/psnz2u36/

Comment: I tested pull-right and pull-left in RTL website. They work perfect, but dropdown-menu-right and dropdown-menu-left not.

Comment: The container (.dropdown) must have a display of "inline-bock". In this example the LI is fine, but if it were a DIV the alignment would be placed at the end of the block element which is influenced by the submenu width.

Comment: The class "dropdown-menu-right" did the trick with Bootstrap 4 (beta) as well. Thanks! "pull-right" did not work.

Comment: using `class="dropdown"` was the key for me in order to get a proper alignment

Comment: With Bootstrap 5 it's the same as Bootstrap 4, except you would use dropdown-menu-end instead of dropdown-menu-right

Answer (score 65):

Not sure about how other people solve this problem or whether Bootstrap has any configuration for this.

I found this thread that provides a solution:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1411

One of the post suggests the use of

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: auto;">
```

I tested and it works.

Hope to know whether Bootstrap provides config for doing this, not via the above css.

Cheers.

Comment: It still works in an existing bootstrap v5.1.0 site (Chrome browser atleast). Earlier I was trying to get my head around the responsive alignment documentation.

dropdown-menu{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl}-end

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#responsive-alignment

Answer (score 21):

Based on Bootstrap doc:

As of v3.1.0, .pull-right is deprecated on dropdown menus.
use .dropdown-menu-right

eg:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
```

Comment: I tested pull-right and pull-left in RTL website. They work perfect, but dropdown-menu-right and dropdown-menu-left not.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to display the menu up, just add the class "dropup" 
and remove the class "dropdown" if exists from the same div.

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
```

[image]

Comment: "I hope that the position of the upper-right corner of the dropdwon is at the lower-right place of the text" -- OP

Comment: I cant understand you comment, sorry!!

Comment: It looks good but, how can we make it automatic ? Like i have list of data and the bottom part is not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Even if it s late i hope i can help someone. if dropdown menu or submenu is on the right side of screen it's open on the left side, if menu or submenu is on the left it's open on the right side.

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function(event){//"show.bs.dropdown"
    var liparent=$(this.parentElement);
    var ulChild=liparent.find('ul');
    var xOffset=liparent.offset().left;
    var alignRight=($(document).width()-xOffset)<xOffset;


    if (liparent.hasClass("dropdown-submenu"))
    {
        ulChild.css("left",alignRight?"-101%":"");
    }
    else
    {                
        ulChild.toggleClass("dropdown-menu-right",alignRight);
    }

});
```

To detect vertical position you can also add

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var liparent=$(".dropdown");
    var yOffset=liparent.offset().top;
        var toTop=($(document).height()-yOffset)<yOffset;
    liparent.toggleClass("dropup",toTop);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jd1100/rf9zvdhg/28/

Comment: can it be adjusted like top and bottom too ? if the dropdown link is at the bottom then I would like to open it to the top direction ? Can we achieve this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to detect vertical position?

Comment: How to do it not relatively side of screen and relatively side of block (div)?
for example:
<div class="card-body">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
   <span class="text-nowrap">Name</span><br><a href="#">Namber</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Boostrap has a class for that called `navbar-right`. So your code will look as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to center the dropdown, this is the solution.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right:auto; left: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do it not relatively side of screen (as a user @JD11 he is answer bottom) and relatively side of block (div)?

for example inside div with class "card-body":

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="text-nowrap">Name</span><br><a href="#">Namber</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```