# How to position dropdown menu with bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 beta. Below is my navbar source. I want to position dropdown menu at right. I did read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment but this is still at left.
This post [Bootstrap dropdown: positioning of dropdown content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904862/bootstrap-dropdown-positioning-of-dropdown-content) did not help as this is for bootstrap 3.
What wrong I did in my code?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using auto-margins (`.ml-auto`):

```html
<!-- css and js files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- your code -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**Explanation:**

- To push the dropdown menu to the right side of the navbar you can use the auto-margin on the left side. Bootstrap 4 provides a class `.ml-auto` (`margin-left:auto;`). So you can use this class on the `<ul class="navbar-nav">`.
- The `dropdown-menu-right` is used to align the dropdown content to the right. If you don't use this class the dropdown content is aligned to the left and overflow on the right side of your website.

You can find more information about auto-margins on the [official docs of Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins).

Comment: Thanks, I see the only difference is <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">. Would you please explain what does ml-auto?