# Javascript, creating button that randomly selects links inside the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

I'm trying to make it so when people select the button on top of the page one of the three links, which are ids inside the page, will be selected (they look like tabs with the jquery ui attachment but I couldn't get it on the pen), but despite my attemps I can't make it work by using a function and if staments, any advice on what I'm doing wrong? I never made something more than basic in javascript

Full code here, since due to character limit i can't put the full HTML and CSS on the post

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bladeranner5005/pen/GRMVGbR

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <!--Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--Font links-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400&family=Libre+Franklin:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Plugins -->
    <link href="../external-files/jquery-ui-1.13.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../external-files/jquery-ui-1.13.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../external-files/jquery-ui-1.13.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../external-files/jquery-ui-1.13.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Custom css-->
    <link href="../css/index-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="../css/content-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



    <title>Andrea D'Angelo-Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- NAVBAR ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--Modified bootstrap NAVBAR, with different colors and positioning when in desktop----------------------------------->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark background-black">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link nav-link-custom-1 nav-item-spacing" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link nav-link-custom-1 nav-item-spacing" href="#">Curriculum</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active nav-link-custom-1 nav-item-spacing" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link nav-link-custom-1 nav-item-spacing" href="#">Contatti</a>

            <!--Codice per il dropdown da: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904862/bootstrap-position-of-dropdown-menu-relative-to-navbar-item-->

            <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-custom-2 nav-item-spacing" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    
            </li>-->
        </div>

        <!--Dropdown item end-->

    </div>
</nav>

<!--Main tag----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<main>

    <!--Name--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <section class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12 text-center background-black mb-5">
                <h1 class="page-title-font">PORTFOLIO</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <!--Random selector------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

    <!--Start container-->
    <footer class="container-fluid">

        <!--ROW 1-->
        <div class="row mb-5 mt-5">

            <!--ROW 1-A-->
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-4"></div>

                            <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
                                <button type="button" class="link-btn-light btn btn-light w-100" id="random-select">Selezione</button>
                            </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-4"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    <!--CONTENT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <section class="container-fluid me-0 ms-0">

        <div class="row">

            <div id="tabs">

                <ul id="tab-id">

                    <li><a href="#heading1" id="pastichair">Pastichair</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#heading2" id="bella-e-brava">Bella e brava</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#heading3" id="personal-space">Personal space</a></li>

                </ul>

              

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $( "#tabs").tabs();

            </script>

        </div>

    </section>



    <!--Footer start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <!--Red line-->
    <div class="border-top border-5 border-danger" style="width: 100%"></div>


    <!--Start container-->
    <footer class="container-fluid">

        <!--ROW 1-->
        <div class="row mb-5 mt-5">

            <!--ROW 1-A-->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-md-0">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="link-btn-light btn btn-light w-100">Home<br>page</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!--ROW 1-B-->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="link-btn-light btn btn-light w-100">Online<br>curriculum</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--ROW 2-->
        <div class="row mb-5 mt-5">

            <!--ROW 2-A-->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mb-5 mb-md-0">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="link-btn-light btn btn-light w-100">Online<br>portfolio</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!--ROW 2-B-->
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                        <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                            <a href="#" class="link-btn-light btn btn-light w-100">Full contacts<br>and info</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-2 col-md-3"></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </footer>

</main>

<!-- Javascript for Bootstrap --------------------->
<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Javascript for Bootstrap END------------------>

<!-- My Javascript -->

<script src="../javascript/portfolio-javascript.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
//Variable declaration

let button = document.getElementById("random-select");

let tab1 = document.getElementById("pastichair");

let tab2 = document.getElementById("bella-e-brava");

let tab3 = document.getElementById("personal-space");

//Array e function, così da creare un numero casuale tra 0 e 2

let array = ["headerA", "headerB", "headerC"];

button.addEventListener("click", tabRandom())

    function tabRandom () {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

        //If statement per selezionare tab casuale

        if (randomNumber === 0) {
            tab1.addEventListener("click", function (){
                document.getElementById("pastichair").click();
            });
        }

        if (randomNumber === 1) {
            tab2.addEventListener("click", function (){
                document.getElementById("bella-e-brava").click();
            });
        }

        if (randomNumber === 2) {
            tab3.addEventListener("click", function (){
                document.getElementById("personal-space").click();
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you could do to make it works.

First, change the callback parameter:

```
// incorrect, this is you execute a function and pass its value as a callback
button.addEventListener("click", tabRandom());

// correct, this is you pass a function as a callback
button.addEventListener("click", tabRandom);
```

Then, inside the `tabRandom()`, you need to remove the `addEventListener` to make the trigger works:

```
// not work, this is you assign an event
tab1.addEventListener("click", function (){
   document.getElementById("pastichair").click();
});

// trigger a click
document.getElementById("pastichair").click();
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/phucbui/pen/VwMoBao)