# Why is dropdown-item not showing?

Tags: html, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 for my navigation bar. The problem is that the dropdown item (Login) for the user icon is not showing. Here's my code:

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user text-white fs-5"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Boostrap 5 you'll need `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` and not `data-toggle`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user text-white fs-5"></i>
</button>            
            
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! it worked but when i click the user icon, the Login button shows on the left. how can i make it show on the right side of navigation bar?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904862/bootstrap-position-of-dropdown-menu-relative-to-navbar-item