# using bootstrap dropdown submenus

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I have a bootstrap navbar I made here wssl.beta.org. The subnav dropdown works as intended until you get to the right side of the page. I'm trying to make the sub nav appear on the right. Right now I have this for the navbar:

```
<li class="nav-item active">
          <a style=" color:#FFBB3F;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            FIELDS
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu-left"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

But it keeps appearing to the right for some reason. I've tried attaching -left to the drop-down menu and that also doesn't work.

Comment: whoops I meant that I'm trying to have the submenu appear to the left. Sorry, I've been looking at a computer all day.

Comment: You mind clarifying your problem?

Comment: sure. if you look at the navbar you'll see it drop downs and there are options to open a submenu. The submenu will  dropdown to the right, which is fine until you reach the right side of the page. Here's a picture of the bug: [link](https://imgur.com/qPYgcWa)

Comment: check my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818359/10997917](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818359/10997917)

Answer (score 1):

Use `<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">` instead of `<li class="dropdown-submenu-left">`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/szx4Y/51/)

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485503/10997917

Comment: so I've actually tried that before it just makes the submenu overlap on top of the menu it doesn't actually [display left.] (https://imgur.com/WGNLk6N)

Comment: If you replace your sub menu with the sub menu from the demo does it work?